# can't cd to /bin/../share/gradle/bin/

Tags: gradle

i installed latest version of gradle, and i wanted to test it and see if it is working, and faced with the error that:

```
/bin/gradle: 23: cd: can't cd to /bin/../share/gradle/bin/..
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
```

i tried to downgrade my gradle but it didn't work for me, i also tried to redeclare my path variable but it also didn't work, im using debian 11 bullseye linux distro. output of `uname -a` ;

```
Linux debian 5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-2 (2023-07-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How did you install Gradle? Normally, unzipping the zip and putting its `bin` path to PATH would work.

Comment: @chehsunliu i installed from official web of gradle and followed the step by step guide it provided